# How to disable Arduino Yun to work as Access Point and set it to work as needed?

Tags: arduino-yun, wifi, networking, ethernet

I am using Arduino Yun and I would like to disable it to work as Access Point. That is, I don't want that it is displayed in the list of available networks.

Then I would like to set and use it (separately) in the following scenarios:

a) Arduino Yun connected just over a given Wi-Fi network (Ethernet connection disabled).

b) Arduino Yun connected just over Ethernet (Wi-Fi connection disabled).

How can I make it?

**Note**: In my previous attempts I tried to customize and/or disable someway the Wi-Fi connection (through the LuCI panel) in order to reach what I am looking for but in all of these cases [I had to restore my Arduino Yun](http://playground.arduino.cc/Hardware/Yun#restoring_a_yun) from scratch because it did not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yun expects wifi to be working and, if it's not, it will reboot itself after 60 seconds and return in access point mode.

In order to disable this check, edit file `/etc/rc.local` and turn `wifi-live-or-reset` into `#wifi-live-or-reset` (with a starting `#`).

Once done, use LuCI (the advanced configuration panel) to configure network interfaces.